# Avoid redundancy code using covariance in object oriented inheritance

Tags: c++11, inheritance, subclass, covariance, redundancy

I know that this problem may have been asked before, but i really do not know what to search for, as I am not even sure about my chosen title.

**What I want to achieve:**
If I use *getMeasurement(int timestep)* with an Integer value not contained in the map of a Sensor object, the asked measurement should be interpolated (if possible) using a measurement specific method *interpolate(...)*.
It should get the correct two Measurements objects from the map to use for the interpolation in the super class Sensor and interpolate them, but I do not know how and if i can call the interpolation. Maybe with Generics/Typename or design patterns.

```
Sensor someSensor = ...
Measurement measurementAt2 = someSensor.getMeasurement(2); 
// should interpolate value if map measurements in someSensor not has the key 2
```

**Additional Info:** *ASensor::measurements* just contains *AMeasurements*.
*BSensor::measurements* just contains *BMeasurements*. ... These measurements contain different value types and therefore each subclass of Measurement needs to be interpolated differently.

```
abstract class Sensor {
   map<int, Measurement> measurements;
   Measurement getMeasurement(int timestep);
}

class ASensor : Sensor {
   ...
}

class BSensor : Sensor {
   ...
}


abstract class Measurement {
   ...
}

class AMeasurement : Measurement {
   AMeasurement interpolate(AMeasurement other, int timestep);
}

class BMeasurement : Measurement {
   BMeasurement interpolate(BMeasurement other, int timestep);
}
```

If I add an abstract/virtual method *Measurement interpolated(Measurement other, int timestep)* in Measurement for inheritance, this signature would not be good for the subclass, as i need to check the class type and also cast the other Measurement.

I appreciate an answer possible to code in C++11, which I am currently using.

**EDIT:** The subclasses ASensor+AMeasurement, BSensor+BMeasurement, ... are all independent loaded plugins if this information is needed.

EDIT2: Added the return types of the methods (which I forgot).

Comment: How are you populating `measurements`?

Comment: Write a little piece of driver code showing how you intend to call the code. Perhaps we can then comment.

Comment: Sensor has a method to read the specific data from a string using an abstract/virtual method in Measurements to create Measurements using just specific parts of the string. This method is implemented differently in each subclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make the `getMeasurement` function in `Sensor` pure virtual then you don't need the `map` in the base class. Then it is up to implementations of `Sensor` to store measurements of their own type and interpolate between them. You can provide a template class to do all the work:

```
class Sensor {
   public:
     virtual std::unique_ptr<Measurement> getMeasurement(int timestep) const = 0;
};

template<typename M>
class BasicSensor : public Sensor {
    std::map<int, M> measurements;
  public:
    std::unique_ptr<Measurement> getMeasurement(int timestep) const override {
        auto itr = measurements.lower_bound(timestep);

        if (itr == measurements.end())  // Cant find measurement equal or later
            return nullptr;             // than timestep so can't interpolate.

        if (itr->first == timestep)                   // Found exact match so
            return std::make_unique<M>(itr->second);  // don't need to interpolate.

        if (itr == measurements.begin()) // Can't find measurement before
            return nullptr;              // timestep so can't interpolate.

        auto interpolated = std::prev(itr)->second.interpolate(itr->second, timestep);

        // Copy to smart-pointer to avoid slicing
        return std::make_unique<M>(interpolated); 
    }
    void setMeasurement(int timestep, const M& m) {
        measurements[timestep] = m;
    }
};

class ASensor : public BasicSensor<AMeasurement> {};
class BSensor : public BasicSensor<BMeasurement> {};
```

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/niudz2aS0eXn0e5u).

Comment: Thank you very much, i even tried to put the map in the subclass but this produced code redundancy for me, but i did not had this idea to put a template class between.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of your question, but in c++ one can get return value covariance. Perhaps something like this would help you (see the comments):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Measurement //Abstract
{
    virtual int apply(int timestep) const = 0;
    virtual std::string name() const = 0;
  protected:
    virtual ~Measurement(){}
  //...virtual Meas... etc
};

struct AMeasurement : Measurement //Implements Measurement for sensorA
{
  std::string name() const override{ return "AMeasurement"; }
  int apply(int timestep) const override
  {
    return timestep * 10;
  }
};
struct BMeasurement : Measurement //Implements Measurement for sensorB
{
  std::string name() const override{ return "BMeasurement"; }
  int apply(int timestep) const override
  {
    return timestep * 20;
  }
};

struct MeasurementProvider //Provides measurement
{
  virtual const Measurement& getMeasurement() const = 0;
  //...etc
  protected:
    virtual ~MeasurementProvider(){}
};

//Generalized measurement provider.
// Covariance ensure correct measurement used. Currently most basic
// implementation. Can elaborate
template <class MeasurementType>
struct GenMeasurementProvider : MeasurementProvider
{
  //NOTE: MeasureType derived from Measurement, hence covariance...
  const MeasurementType& getMeasurement() const override{return m_;}
  MeasurementType m_;
};

// Perhaps Sensor is just a generalized Provider.
struct SensorA : GenMeasurementProvider<AMeasurement>
{
};

// Interpolate using provider instead of actual measurement to
// allow for covariance.
void interpolate(const MeasurementProvider& provider, int timestep)
{
  //return type allows covariance, therefore apply to be
  // called on correct type
  auto const& measurement = provider.getMeasurement();

  std::cout << "Result of measurement " << measurement.name() 
            << ":" << measurement.apply(timestep) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  const int timestep = 100;
  interpolate(GenMeasurementProvider<AMeasurement>{}, timestep);
  interpolate(GenMeasurementProvider<BMeasurement>{}, timestep);
  interpolate(SensorA{}, timestep);
  return 0;
}
```

I've omitted allot of detail that I'll perhaps color in with more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is the signature of `interpolate()`, I suppose you could transform `Measurement` in a template class depending from the derived class; something like

```
template <typename Derived>
class Measurement {
   Derived interpolate (Derived other, int timestep)
    { /* do something */ }
};

class AMeasurement : Measurement<AMeasurement> {
   // ...
};

class BMeasurement : Measurement<BMeasurement> {
   // ...
};
```

p.s.: sorry for my bad English

Comment: Isn't now the Problem, that i can't put these different Measurements in a map together. What would be my super class?

Comment: @AndreMeixner Why do you need to put all these different measurements in a map together? Each sensor only has measurements of its own type right?

Comment: If I would put a map of specific measurements in the suitable sensor, it would cause other problems. Example: To implement a getter in sensor i need to cast each measurement subclass before returning.

Comment: @AndreMeixner Up-casts to `Measurement` for the getter can be done implicitly and are safe.